# PHP : Post get method, need some advice

Tags: php

I am new to php and need to understand how post get method could be useful for my code. My scenario is, I have 3 webpages, 1st webpage is an html form , I am using post method here then I take firstname and last name from form and enter in a sql query(for e.g. `$_POST[firstname]`) on 2nd webpage which generates some data for me and I am printing that data.

Now I need to pass same parameters to 3rd page which generates some graph based on firstname and lastname entered in 1st HTML form?

How can I persist these values on 3rd php page? I am referencing url for page 3 on page and I believe that is not sufficient, I tried Google search and found out post get could be useful however need some expert advice.

Thanks

Comment: if you google or search in Stackoverflow itself you will find unlimited answers on this. please search once before post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

**1st page (page1.php)**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**2nd (page2.php)**

Retrieve and validate `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['lastname']`, then create an output with your required data, you can use hidden fields or create links, according your needs. For instance:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];

// Output with links can pass data by GET method
echo '<a href="page3.php?firstname='.$firstname.'&lastname='.$lastname.'"></a>';

// Output with hidden fields, you can use POST or GET method or even Javascript/Ajax
echo '
<form action="page3.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'.$firstname.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="'.$lastname.'" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';
```

**3rd page (page3.php)**

If you use the solution with a link or with a form with GET method, you can retrieve the data in `page3.php` just doing the following:

```
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname  = $_GET['lastname'];
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Marcio, I did not understand 2nd part of the code, here newpage means 2nd page or 3rd page?

Comment: @yokoyoko, I've removed the last comment because i saw again your comment and based on your question `newpage.php` will be the 3rd page. I am doing some changes in the answer, please see it again.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP sessions to store the data between PHP pages. Alternatively, you can just pull the data you already added to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `$_SESSION` variable.

[Read about it here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/)

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of would be to put the values from the first page into a hidden field on the second page that would be submitted with the form on the second page:

```
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Of course you want to make sure that you validate and sanitize your inputs, etc. if any of this is going into a database or could otherwise affect the security and durability of your site.